# Angular Change Detection OnPush - How to Pass Ngrx Store Observable From Container to Child Component

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a container component which has `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. I have an Observable property which is set to a property in the Ngrx Store:

```
public isiShadowLocations$: Observable<IIsiShadowLocation[]>;
...
ngOnInit() {

  this.isiShadowLocations$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromPlan.getIsiShadowLocations));
}
```

I am trying to pass this Observable to a child component for it to render the changing value in the template as follows:

```
<app-plan-isi-shadow-display [isiShadowLocations]="isiShadowLocations$ | async"></app-plan-isi-shadow-display>
```

In my child component I have an `@Input()` property as follows:

```
@Input() isiShadowLocations: IIsiShadowLocation[];
```

And finally in the child template I consume the array using an `*ngFor` as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let isiShadowLocation of isiShadowLocations">
```

When I run the app and check, using the Chrome Ngrx DevTools, the array property in the `Store` is changing, however my parent container component does not appear to be aware of the changes (or it is and they are not being passed to the child correctly). I was under the impression that the `async` pipe would enable change detection using `OnPush`. Could it be that I should pass the Observable to the child and then use the `async` pipe within the child component?

Can anyone see where I am going wrong please?

Comment: You either use @Input or ngRx Store for your components communication.

Comment: I was under the impression that my presentation component should have no knowledge of the Ngrx Store and have its values provided using `@Input()`. My corresponding container component is responsible for obtaining the values from the Ngrx Store and passes them down to the child presentations component which in return will use `@Output()` to pass events back. I'm not sure how you could use only `@Input()` or `NgRx Store`?

Comment: Oh sorry, this is not available when talking about smart/dumb components.

Comment: is there a typo somewhere? Your smart/dumb component logic is correct. If you have a stackblitz I can take a look.

Comment: In case it is significant, it is the parent to my 'container' component which has its change detection set to `OnPush`.

Comment: how does your reducer look like?

Comment: How is the array changing? It has to be a new array (new instance) for the change detection to work. Is your state immutable?

Comment: Rémi this is just where I was looking. I assumed that because my Reducer spread the State when setting the updated array in the Store, the array would be a new object, but it appears not. If I spread the array and then update the value and dispatch this in my action to update everything works.